# Why some identifiers in the standard C++ library are short?

Tags: c++

Why are some C++ names short and sometimes hard to understand like `strcmp`,
`cout`, `cin`, etc. But in other languages like Java name are not short. Does it save time, memory or what?

Comment: Because people are lazy, and laziness moves the world. (:

Comment: But isn't readablity more important.

Comment: In pre C89 standards, the significant portion of external identifiers has been 6 characters. Linkers were allowed to ignore the remaining characters. That is why the standard library limited identifier length to 6 characters.

Comment: @Motubet In my experience _typeability_ is even more important. Once you start naming things `classHashCodeCountIndexLookupTable` (a variable I actually used once), coding even simple operations becomes very arduous.

Comment: This is not an opinion-based question, and putting it on hold is inappropriate. There are factual explanations for the naming conventions in C and C++.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Re typeability: It should also be said that in earlier days many programs were typed in on an ASR-33 teletype, which is a very slow and painful way to type!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This primarily applies to the portions of the standard C++ library that have been "inherited" from C. In pre-C89 standards of the C language the significant portion of external identifiers has been limited to 6 characters; linkers were allowed to ignore the remaining characters. That is why the standard C library limited identifier length to 6 characters. C++ incorporated that library "wholesale", along with somewhat cryptic identifiers.

Comment: What about cout and cin couldn't they change cout to echo and cin to read.

Comment: @Motubet I would write them off as "bad influence" of the C library: in C, the standard file descriptors are called `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`; C++ designers (most likely, Stroustrup himself) replaced `std` ("standard") with `c` ("character"), and kept the old suffixes.

Answer (score 1):

There are parts of the C++ Standard libraries that are derived from the older C Standard Library.  The older C Standard Library in turn was derived from the older K&R library that provided some of the basic functionality through functions which in other languages are built into the language such as Input/Output.

This section of the book [Rationale for the ANSI C Programming Language](http://books.google.com/books?id=yxLISD0TAbEC&lpg=PA20&ots=tDUzoDW4jE&dq=length%20of%20external%20identifiers%20in%20C&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q=length%20of%20external%20identifiers%20in%20C&f=false) provides a description of the naming conventions for C identifiers.

The C programming language is compiled and the machine code output of the compiler is linked together into the actual applications.  The software that does the linking is typically part of the standard tools offered by an operating system vendor.  A survey of the available linker applications offered by various vendors found that the most basic provided six characters for the external identifiers that could be processed by the linkers.  Some linkers allowed more however by specifying a limit of six characters, the list of available target computers for C compilers was much larger.

By staying with the limits of the linkers, it allowed C programmers to write C programs and function libraries that could be used with software written in other languages as well as allowed the use of libraries written in other languages to be used by C programmers.

Answer (score 0):

C++ inherits from C which was built long-long ago by programmers who were used to working in assembler.

But I think it goes deeper into the mathematical background of programmers. There were early attempts to make languages easier to understand by using English terms, COBOL and SQL are probably the only survivors. But since words in programming languages have a very precise meaning, using 'SELECT' rather than a colon only helps a small amount, you still need to know all the details of SQL to write the rest of the query.

Short identifiers make the code easier to understand for experienced programmers, you can see and parse more of the structure in a single glance. If you ever have to read scientific papers from the C17-C18 where they use a page of prose to describe what we would write in a single equation - you will understand.